# How to use fail2ban to parse Nginx access log to count 404's and ban ip addresses?

Tags: nginx, iptables, brute-force-attacks, fail2ban

How can I use fail2ban to parse Nginx access log to count 404's and 502's, and ban ip addresses with too many requests?

Answer (score 1):

there is an article about this http://codelog.climens.net/2011/02/13/using-fail2ban-with-nginx-in-debian/